# Correlations between categorical and continuous variables in a mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity

I have a dataset with two independent predictors, one categorical (6 levels) and one continuous. I'm also including an interaction term and a random effect of site. 
$$
yij=β0+β1*x1ij+β2*x2ij+β3*x1ij*x2ij+uj+εij
$$

For two of the categorical levels, the continuous variable is signifigantly higher than the other levels. This is primarily driven by strong clustering in two of the six sites. However, I'm interested in designing a linear model that tests for relationships with both predictors as both can influence the response independently. Is this valid with a linear mixed effects model? Or is the relationship between the predictors invalidate the inference? If I predict means of each category while 'controlling' for the continuous variable, it essentially compares the means of the two extremes for the low- and high-level categories ('i.e. best vs. worst).